# Multiple images shown from one drop downmenu

Tags: javascript, html, perl, drop-down-menu

I am trying to change more than one image at the same time with separate images.
perl is changing the path for images for me.

```
function swapImage(){
var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
var image2 = document.getElementById("imageToSwap2");
var image3 = document.getElementById("imageToSwap3");
var dropd = document.getElementById("dd");
image.src = dropd.value;    
    image2.src=arr[dropd.value];
    image3.src=arr[dropd.value];
```

};

```
  <select name="buttonstuff"  id="dd" onChange="swapImage()">
              <option value="http://upperboards.com/hosted/images/buttonset/but-lpurple/homepage.gif" selected>but-purple</option>
              <option value="http://upperboards.com/hosted/images/buttonset/but-red/homepage.gif">but-red</option>
               <option value="http://upperboards.com/hosted/images/buttonset/but-green/homepage.gif">but-green</option>
               </select>
               <img id="imageToSwap" src="http://upperboards.com/hosted/images/buttonset/but-lpurple/homepage.gif"/>
               <img id="imageToSwap2" src="http://upperboards.com/hosted/images/buttonset/but-lpurple/icq.gif"/>
               <img id="imageToSwap3" src="http://upperboards.com/hosted/images/buttonset/but-lpurple/aim.gif"/>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am trying to display more than one image at the same time from the drop menu. And I can only change one image from the 2 images at once. is there a way to change two separate images at the same time from one menu?

Comment: Please build it in http://jsfiddle.net/ with real data. The piece of string from your Perl code does not help at all because we do not know what `$options` is. I'm still not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: There is no BBCode on SO. You can [edit] your question. Use Markdown instead of BBCode. [There is also an FAQ document about Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bur4T/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your images are all in the same folder, you can use that folder as the `value` for your `<option>`s. That makes it quite simple to change all the images.

HTML:

```
<select name="buttonstuff" id="dd" onChange="foo()">
    <option value="but-lpurple" selected>but-purple</option>
    <option value="but-red">but-red</option>
    <option value="but-green">but-green</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var url = 'http://upperboards.com/hosted/images/buttonset/';
function foo() {
    var colorscheme = document.getElementById("dd").value;
    document.getElementById("imageToSwap").src  = url + colorscheme + '/homepage.gif';
    document.getElementById("imageToSwap2").src = url + colorscheme + '/icq.gif';
    document.getElementById("imageToSwap3").src = url + colorscheme + '/aim.gif';
};
```

[I've updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bur4T/3/).

Comment: That is so close but, the folder does change from the <option> but uses the same image names. each folder has same picture names inside but different colored gif files. so I am trying to switch folders which i have done in <option> with the same file names and it changes the colors of the gif files.

Comment: I don't understand that. Can you try to say that in more sentences with less words? :P

Comment: OK here is a screenshot of what I am doing http://www.upperboards.com/a/switcharoo.jpg and the drop down has the folder names lchoices where the files are located which is in the <option>

Comment: Let me recap what I understood. The `select` has a list of folder names. On the server, these folders each have a bunch of images with the same names. When you change the `select`, it changes the `src` attributes of the `img`es. That's what my example does.

Comment: <option value="$dap/images/buttonset/$opts/homepage.gif" $bansc>$opts</option>

Comment: OK, not that is Perl and HTML again. Please [edit] your question and add the complete Perl code. I believe there is a loop. I want to see that.

Comment: I'm not going to retype all of this. But I have an idea what the problem is. Please do [edit] your question. Click the [edit] link. Post the code from the screenshot inside the question. I'll be back later to look at it.

Comment: http://www.upperboards.com/a/tester3.jpg screenshot of code. It seems to be working now! the only thing i need to figure out how to match "selected"<option> with the image.

Comment: Its working perfect with that example you gave me. I just needed to update the perl code! Thank you very much!